# How to set default process scheduling priority ('nice' value) for all remotely logged users?

Tags: linux, unix, administration

My desktop allows remote access. I work locally, sometimes other people log in, using ssh/telnet/ftp/rsh. Their processes get the same priority as my own.

I would like to set priority ('nice' value) of all processes for people logged in remotely to some higher value, e.g. 10. How can I do that?

I tried using pam_group to dynamically assign a group for such people and then pam_limits to set the priority, but there are two problems:

1. it seems pam_limits does not use/see the group that was set by pam_group. I've checked that the group is set after remote login, and that the priority is correctly changed when limiting username, not dynamically set group.
2. I'm not sure I can set the limits for all services, like telnet or rsh - at least I haven't seen any files with such name in /etc/pam.d

I can't hardcode list of users in limits.conf, as I'm using NIS.
Is there any other way? What I want to achieve is to be able to work without decreased performance caused by other (remote) users...

Comment: This question belongs on serverfault.com. Perhaps it is easier for you to give yourself higher priority instead of giving everybody else lower priority..

Answer (score 1):

The *default* priority (nice level) can be set via `/etc/security/limits.conf`. Example:

```
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
mary           hard    priority       15
```

Note that `<item>` must be `priority`, not `nice` which has a different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to set the nice priority for currently running apps, you can look at 'renice'.  It even takes a user/group parameter so you can specify all processes for said user/group.

As for setting a default priority, I'm not certain.  I'm researching it currently, I'll add another answer if I find something.

Comment: Hi @Eddie Parker 

Can't you achieve this by changing the app (let's say zoom) running group, and set that group to have such limit in the `/securty` ?